# Horizontal scrollbar showing white space on right of webpage?

Tags: css

This is the page in question: https://globalstudyuk.com/home-page-test/

You will see that on both desktop and mobile, there is some blank space on the right of the page.

I haven't found any solution in my code based on similar StackOverflow questions.

There should be no horizontal scrollbar, with everything filling the full width of the page.

Comment: `#footer .row` you have negative left/right margins, remove to fix

Comment: Also, you should remove the `<br>` tags in between your different divs. Use margin for top/bottoms spacing.

Comment: Please place the relevant code IN the question as remote links may be changed  or deleted and thus the question become dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the final .row inside the .container in the footer.

The negative margin on the .row is countered by the padding on the .container class.

Always useful to revisit the Bootstrap docs when things go awry:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or very similar problem. Making the window more narrow everything seemed to resize correctly, except a horizontal scrollbar appeared at the bottom. When I scrolled with it, white-space appeared on the right side of the page.

Turns out the reason was that on the top of the page I had an element with width 100%. But under that I had another piece of text inside a  PRE -section, with lines that were quite wide, wider than the resized window-width.

When I made the window more narrow the top element resized correctly but the PRE -element no longer fit into the horizontal space available, thus creating the horizontal scrollbar.

When I used that scrollbar the browser (of course) did not resize the content on the top of the page, because I was not resizing the window, only scrolling it horizontally.

Therefore the browser did not readjust the top element after the scroll to take 100% of the new visible width and therefore it could only show whitespace to the right of it as I scrolled.

So if you have this type of problem, check out if there are any DOM-elements below the currently visible ones, and whether they might be the cause of the horizontal scrollbar.

My particular problem was solved by making the PRE-section defined  like this:

```
<pre style="width:100%; overflow-x: auto; "
> ...
```

Now when I make the page too narrow for the PRE-content to fit in horizontally, a horizontal scrollbar appears, but now only under the PRE-section. Scrolling it only scrolls (horizontally) the PRE-section, not the whole page. When I scroll vertically to the top of the page I don't see the PRE-section nor the horizontal scrollbar under it.